# Is there a way to log that an error has occurred because of session timeout

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session, elmah

We're getting a lot of

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

And I've spoken to some customers about what they were doing when it happened. The answer I've been getting is that they were afk for a bit and they came back and session had timed out.

Now I know I can check for session and redirect customers in code - however extensive that maybe. What I would like to know about are any "cover-all" techniques that could redirect actions before they throw errors. And, more importantly, how I could log in Elmah that the error (or previous Error) was due to a session timeout. I'm not wanting to log every sessions timeout, that would be silly, but something like on Application Error - check for session timeout - report it as so.

--More Information--
I've inherited this project and it's about 330,000 lines of code, I do not have the time to check/refactor it all, nor can I rely on these errors being thrown to catch them, I'm already doing that, I'm trying to identify those errors worth investigating.

Answer (score 0):

If you're relying on the values from a session then you should probably proactively check that the values in the session exist

You could set a session variable on log in called "MyKey" and use something like below to check that it hasn't timed out:

```
if (Session["MyKey"] == null)  {
    //Code here to log session timeout error
    ...
    // Code here to redirect to login page
    ...
}
```

That way you shouldn't be throwing exception which have an overhead and you can redirect the user to a non-error page should the session have timed out.

Comment: See my edits; basically, there's too much code to add that in retrospectively.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22090365/action-filter-to-check-session-mvc3 - something like this might be useful to you then. Adding a filter that you should be able to add a controller level.